# APK file res directory files with same names

Tags: android, android-studio, duplicates, apk

I need to submit my apk to a third party for signing before it goes on their closed app store. Their signing tool runs on windows and unzips the apk.

Since around the end of June something has changed (possibly I updated Android Studio) to the release apk that gets generated by Android Studio. The res folder structure is no longer included, and there are lots of .xml files created inside the folder, many with duplicate filenames (according to windows since it's case insensitive). For example there is a gZ.xml and a Gz.xml. This is causing a problem because the apk cannot be unzipped now on a windows machine.

I'm trying to get Android Studio to go back to the old way of including the full directory structure and I've assumed that the flattening of the folders, renaming of files, and addition of xml files is some sort of obfuscation.

This is the current res folder structure in the apk:

[image: new apk res structure]

This is the old folder structure within the apk from an April release (which I'd like to get back to):
[image: old res structure in apk]

The things I have tried so far to stop this obfuscation, if that's what it is:

`minifyEnabled false` in build.gradle

`-dontobfuscate` in ProGuard-rules.txt

`android.enableR8=false` in gradle.properties

I even tried building on a windows machine, but it's always the same result.

I'd be grateful if anyone could point me to a build setting, or whatever it is that I can use that will give me the full folder structure within the apk.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am sorry but how should we help you with an unknown undocumented proprietary APK signing performed by someone you don't even mention?

Comment: Sorry, I've now edited my question to be clearer. The mention of the reason I need to figure this out was maybe confusing, and distracting from the actual question. I only want to know how to keep the res folder structure in the release apk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on some quick experiments I just ran, it looks like you have two options:

1. Add `android.enableResourceOptimizations=false` to your `gradle.properties`
   file
2. Keep your Android Gradle Plugin at 4.1.3 or lower

Keep an eye on these issues:

- [The one where I found the solution](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185532483)
- [Another related bug report referenced from the first one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184666005)